# How to copy values in merged cells from one worksheet to another?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet called "main" that takes values from another file's sheet called "data".

With "ActiveSheet.copy" (in the "main" file) it copies the sheet but with the cells' links.

Is there any way to copy just the values of the sheet?

Second, my "main" sheet has some merged cells so even if I manually copy & paste the sheets by selecting a range it can't be copied due to the merged cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the options you get with `PasteSpecial`:

- **Values**: this will not copy links and just values only
- **All except borders**: this will retain merged cell formatting

Example - suppose you want to copy sheet1 to sheet 2 where sheet 1 has merged cells

- In Sheet1 press `CTRL + A` to select all and then `CTRL + C` to copy
- In Sheet2 select cell A1
- Now right click and select `Paste Special...`
- In the dialog box select `All except borders...`

**Updated - VBA**

```
Sub CopyWithMergedCells()
    ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy //select all cells on sheet1 and copy
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Select 
    Cells.Select //select all cells on sheet2
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllExceptBorders, Operation:=xlNone,    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False //paste with formats preserved
End Sub
```

`Paste:=xlPasteAllExceptBorders` is the key bit. You need to change this if you want to just copy values (and not links)

Comment: and their is a way to do this with VBA ?

Comment: see edited answer...best bet is to use macro recorder and then modify the code as you need it...